Who was the first to find integer solutions to $n^2 + (n+1)^2 = k^2$?
Does anyone know who was the first to find solutions in integers for $n^2 + (n+1)^2 = k^2$ (almost isosceles Pythagorean triples)? Who proved (if that's the case) that there are no other solutions apart from
$$
t = \frac{(3+2\sqrt{2})^n}{4}+\frac{(3-2\sqrt{2})^n}{4}-\frac{1}{2}, \hspace{5mm} d = \frac{(3+2\sqrt{2})^n}{4\sqrt{2}}-\frac{(3-2\sqrt{2})^n}{4\sqrt{2}}?$$

Are you talking about this?  Or this?  "Triangular Numbers" have a standard meaning....

Yes, but the questions are 1) who was the first, 2) who proved there are no other solutions? Euler found solutions, there are infinitely many of them, but is it proven that there are no others?

Which one?  I'm guessing you mean the second one (right triangles) which has nothing to do with "Triangular Numbers".  I suggest changing the header of your question.  In any case, This instance of Pell's equation has been studied for millennia, as discussed in that link.  I don't know that things were properly formalized before Euler and Legrange, but this instance was well understood long before then.

@Vika: The dedicated History of Science and Math SE may be a better place for a question like this. ... Cheers!

@Lulu: I wasn't able to find the answer if it was proven (and by whom) that there are no other solutions.

"No other solutions" other than  what?

You haven't provided any set of solutions at all.  Look up the theory of Pell's equation.  Certainly the modern version (continued fractions) is enough.  I am not sure whether earlier people working on this had what we'd agree was a rigorous proof or not...I'd be inclined to doubt it, but I also doubt that solid records go back that far.  My sense is that they were primarily interested in generating good rational approximations to $\sqrt 2$ and less interested in rigorously proving that they hadn't missed any.  But I could have that wrong.

It was known during the Old Babylonian period (c. 1800 BCE) that there is a rectangle with sides 119 and 120 and diagonal 169 and a rectangle with sides 3 and 4 and diagonal 5. See https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00407-011-0083-4.

Diophantus   knew  the recipe $x = 2mn, ; y = m^2 - n^2, ; z = m^2 + n^2 ; . ; ; $   The other direction, that every primitive  right triangle with integer sides comes from that recipe,  is attributed to an anonymous Arabic manuscript of 972 a.d.  Using this, all solutions have $m+n$ odd   and either $m^2 - 2mn - n^2 = 1$ or $m^2 - 2mn - n^2 = -1.$   That is, $(m+n)^2 - 2 n^2 = \pm 1,$ a Pell equation, as advertised

from Dickson, History of the Theory of Numbers, volume II: Diophantine Analysis. Chapter 4, especially pages 165 and 166

@Will Jagy: It is clear for general Pythagorean triples. I need it for "almost isosceles Pythagorean triples" as written in the equation.

@MGD: other than the ones provided by Euler, for example (edited the question).

The first "almost isosceles Pythagorean triple" is $(3,4,5)$, next is $(20,21,29)$. The formulas presented as solutions for $t$ and $d$ yield $(1,1)$ for $n=1$ and $(8,6)$ for $n=2$ -- alas, I can't see (yet) a relation of $t$ and $d$ with "almost isosceles Pythagorean triples." Please explain for dummies.

I can show you 3 ways to generate these but the history of where it started is harder to pin down.

While the exact discovery of "nearly isosceles Pythagorean triangles" isn't attributed to a single person, the concept is generally understood within the framework of the Pythagorean Theorem, which is credited to the ancient Greek mathematician Pythagoras; however, evidence suggests that knowledge of Pythagorean triples (including those that could be considered "nearly isosceles") existed in ancient Babylonian mathematics before Pythagoras' time.
